# TFS 2015 connection with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, tfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to connect my TFS-2015 residing on one machine to the SQL Server 2014 residing on another machine.

This is my SQL Server instance name:

[image]

This is the error I get on TFS:

[image]

Please guide me the fix here.

Comment: How did you launch the wizard? It appears to only be prompting you for an *instance* name and not a *server* name there. I believe you'd want to be using the `Advanced` configuration wizard, but cannot remember the exact wording on all pages leading up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a firewall setting on the sql server.  Can you connect using SSMS from another machine in your network?  Are you using the default port?  If so is there a firewall rule allowing traffic on 1433?

If connection is not the problem then it looks like a user right issue.  The account running TFS and if it is different the account installing TFS will need a proper login to SQL.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2010/08/20/database-permissions-required-to-configure-tfs/

Comment: I have firewall off on all the systems.Yes I am able to connect to SSMS from local as well as I connected to my DB using Visual Studio 2015 server explorer on anther system by providing database username and password.Where In TFS I need to enter the account settings for my sqlserver 2014?

Comment: It is actually the user logged into the server you are installing TFS on.  The path of least resistance is to grant that account sysadmin while doing the install.  I am not 100% sure but I believe that TFS will create user accounts it needs for day to day operation, so that you can remove the account used during setup after the install.  Or if user existed before install, reduce permissions from sysadmin to what it was before.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your screenshot: You only gave it a SQL instance name (`MSSQLSERVER`). You have to provide a database server name as well. How is it going to know what server to connect to otherwise?